# street view display a user set pace and route

Tags: javascript, api, google-street-view

I am not familiar with street view API and from what I have seen using motion tracking only applies to view not direction. What I am trying to do is allow the user to input a speed of travel and either max distance or max duration and virtually walk from a to b without using any controls, but if it is possible to use motion tracking to follow a route that would be ok also. Not asking for any code or functions here, just want to know if the api can support this idea. If I could develop this it would allow me to virtually walk from a hotel to beach, bar or restaurant and see how long it really takes at a normal pace.
Cheers,
Peadar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ This website is more about correcting code that has already been written and which may have issues that you're seeking help with _ You might be better consulting Aoogle's API documentation for the information that you're seeking _ Please take a moment to visit the Help Center and specifically the section on 'Asking' for more details on writing questions >>> stackoverflow.com/help/asking